# Ionic 4: Issue Running Livereload with Environment Configuration Options

Tags: angular, ionic4

I seem to be having an issue using both the configuration flag and the livereload flag when running my Ionic 4 app on an emulator or device. I set my environments up according to the docs here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run

and here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/appflow/quickstart/environment

This cli command will correctly set the environment:

```
ionic cordova emulate android --configuration=qa
```

And this will correctly run with livereload:

```
ionic cordova emulate android --livereload
```

But when I attempt to combine the flags:

```
ionic cordova emulate android --livereload --configuration=qa
```

I get an error: 
Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(browserTarget).

Here's my ionic info if it helps, any insight would be appreciated:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.2
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.2, (and 20 other plugins)
```

Comment: try commenting BrowserSupport : true in angular.json file. hope it helps.

Comment: Can you share your angular.json file? Looks like you have some extra option on your `qa` configuration which is causing the issue.

Comment: Two things that I want you to try: 
-Generate a build from the ionic app flow with your environment set
-Use the environment ambient variable (BUILD_ENV) on your package.json as shown on your link (ionic v3).
If they work could you tell me so I can post an answer?

Comment: Have you tried running it like this:
`ionic cordova emulate android --livereload -- --configuration=qa`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest angular devkit updates:

`npm i @angular-devkit/architect@latest @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest @angular-devkit/core@latest @angular-devkit/schematics@latest`

Answer (score 0):

#1: Open `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

#2: Add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in the tag (Tag application already exists):

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

*`<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">` may be needed just for API level > 28.*

#3: Run live reload with the host of your PC.

```
ionic cordova emulate android -l --address=192.168.2.106 --configuration=qa
```

*INSTEAD OF 192.168.2.106 YOU PUT YOUR PC'S ADDRESS.*

#4: After run Android Studio with a connected device as usual.